# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>' to 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What am I missing in the following code? I want to sort the list by Text

```
public SelectList MyList { get; set; }
MyList = new SelectList(new SelectListItem[] { 
            new SelectListItem {  
                Text = "Select Customer", Value = "", Selected = false 
            } 
        }.Concat(myList.GetAll().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Customer.Name + " - " + x.Name, Value = x.ID.ToString() })), "Value", "Text", "0");
        MyList = MyList .OrderBy(x => x.Text);
```

I am having the error on the last line when compiling.

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable' to
>   'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'. An explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?)

Comment: Impossible to tell without knowing what the constructor of SelectList looks like.

Comment: @Dennis_E, [here you go](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx).

Comment: @AndreiV : Content not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to sort the `SelectList` object as it was a list. Sort the source for the `SelectList`. You probably want to exclude the first one from the sorting:

```
MyList = new SelectList(
  new SelectListItem[] { 
    new SelectListItem {  
      Text = "Select Customer", Value = "", Selected = false 
    } 
  }.Concat(
    myList.GetAll()
      .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Customer.Name + " - " + x.Name, Value = x.ID.ToString() })
      .OrderBy(x => x.Text)
), "Value", "Text", "0");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move the `OrderBy` inside the constructor argument. Actually, you probably want to keep the first element at the start of the list so the `OrderBy` should be applied inside the `Concat`. Also, I have refactored the code to make it somewhat easier to understand what is going on:

```
var items = myList
  .GetAll()
  .Select(
    x => new SelectListItem {
      Text = x.Customer.Name + " - " + x.Name,
      Value = x.ID.ToString()
    }
  )
  .OrderBy(x => x.Text);

var itemsWithInitialItem = new SelectListItem[] {
    new SelectListItem {  
      Text = "Select Customer", Value = "", Selected = false 
    } 
  }
  .Concat(items);

MyList = new SelectList(itemsWithInitialItem, "Value", "Text", "0");
```